# Hitting enter in form calling wrong button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

HTML:

```
<form target="" method="post">
    <input name="username" type="text" />
    <input name="password" type="password" />
    <button>Cancel</button>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n9Lpcqyr/

Problem: When I hit enter, **both** buttons get triggered. Tested with this jQuery:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    alert('help');
});
$("form").submit(function(){
    alert('hey');
});
```

Because the first `<button>` is mapped to `.remove()` the dialog, the form no longer exists to be submitted. I know I can bind the enter key to the `input`s with js, but I'm looking for an HTML-only solution. I tried `tabindex` with no luck. What else can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You could move the cancel button outside of the form, like so (and use CSS to style):

```
<form target="" method="post">
    <input name="username" type="text" />
    <input name="password" type="password" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
<button>Cancel</button>
```